# Having a trouble with opening FIFO in C

Tags: c, file-io, fifo, mkfifo

I'm having a trouble in opening FIFOs in C.. first I created them using mkfifo() function with permission : 0777, and when I tried to open them, it succeeded in opening the first FIFO only, then the process will stuck in opening the second FIFO, and this is my code :

```
fd1 = open("FIFO1_PATH", O_WRONLY );
fd2 = open("FIFO2_PATH", O_WRONLY );
```

This will not be executed, but once I comment the second line, it executes ! Is there a limit for the number of opening FIFOs per process ? I don't know why is this happening.. I just spent 3 Hours trying to figure out what the problem is, but without any results :(

Comment: LOL .. I GOT the problem :D .. I was supposed to open them with "O_NONBLOCK" option, because it will block in the first open() forever (if we suppose no other process will open for reading) .. Thanks

Comment: @user Good for you! Please post your solution as an answer.

Comment: I Got another problem :(, the open will execute but will return -1..

Comment: if stuff returns -1, inspect errno (or e.g. call perror() ) to learn why the thing failed

Comment: Note that you never want to execute a FIFO, so there is no good reason to set the 'x' bit on the permissions; use 666 permission if you must; worry about whether all the world and his dog should be able to write to your FIFO (sometimes the answer is yes, they should; sometimes, it is not a good idea).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer you question about limits - default in Linux is 1024 file descriptors for a process.  Your problem is probably not opening the second FIFO for reading so open for writing blocks.

Comment: Oh, sorry I forgot to mention that I'm trying to open two different FIFOs :)

Comment: Ah, are you sure that the second fifo is opened for reading also?  Otherwise open for writing will block.

Answer (score 5):

I just got it right :)

I have to let the opening process wait until some other process opens the FIFO for reading (and it will be a blocked reading).. by doing sleep on the writing process I will ensure that the other process will opens for reading ..