# Debugging open() command call with truss

Tags: c, unix, file-io, sparc, truss

Using `truss -t'open' $(program_call)` I get:

```
open("command.txt", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK)      = 5
response FIFO file descriptor = -1
// Open call was literally sandwiched between print commands, but its not here?
response FIFO file descriptor = 9
open("response.txt", O_WRONLY|O_NONBLOCK)     Err#6 ENXIO
response.txt: No such device or address
```

The thing is, I initialized the file descriptor to -1, so I KNOW that the open call must have succeeded because it changed the value of the variable. The file descriptor is literally initialized to -1, then somehow gets changed to 9 in the open command call (otherwise the program would end there) but yet the open call does NOT show up in the `truss` call, and the computer does not recognize it as being open.

Some code:

```
if ((outfd = open(CMD_FIFO_NAME, O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK)) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Client: Failed to open %s FIFO.\n", CMD_FIFO_NAME);
    exit(1);
}
printf("RESP_FIFO FILE DESCRIPTOR: %d\n", infd);
/* Open the response FIFO for non-blocking reads. */
if ((infd = open(RESP_FIFO_NAME, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK)) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Client: Failed to open %s FIFO.\n", RESP_FIFO_NAME);
    exit(1);
}
else printf("RESP_FIFO FILE DESCRIPTOR: %d\n", infd);
```

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: Most of it's here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16395947/fifo-issue-with-concurrent-processes

Comment: Ah so its multithreaded. Did you notice this in the truss man-page Notes section:"The trace output for multiple processes or for a multithreaded process (one that contains more than one LWP) is not produced in strict time order. For example, a read() on a pipe can be reported before the corresponding write(). For any one LWP (a traditional process contains only one), the output is strictly time-ordered."

Comment: Yes but regardless the open call is not getting executed. It's not the order. It's literally not being executed.

Comment: I left a suggestion for fix in your other question.

Comment: Maybe parent change the fd? Add "-f" option to truss.

Comment: `29023:  open("response.txt", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK)       = 9` I found the open call with the -f flag, but it still doesn't seem to be working properly as `29021:  open("response.txt", O_WRONLY|O_NONBLOCK)       Err#6 ENXIO` force closes the program. I guess that means the call comes first for some reason...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`truss -f -t'open,close,read,write' run.sh` was useful enough to find my errors, where `run.sh` was a bash file containing the proper execution of my program.